# What is the correct order to traverse the states in the popular Coin-Change dynamic programming question?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I was solving this(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change/copy-from/188149763) problem on `Hackerrank` which can be summarized as follows :

> Find the total number ways to exchange a certain value with the given set of coin denominations.

Here is my code which got accepted:

```
long getWays(int n, vector<long> c) {
    long dp[n+1];
    memset(dp, 0ll, sizeof(dp));
    dp[0] = 1;
    for(int ci=1; ci<=c.size(); ci++)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(c[ci-1] > i) continue;
            dp[i] += dp[i-c[ci-1]];
        }
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

Here **n** is the total value we are supposed to get and **c** is the array of coins.
My question is if I reverse the order of loops i.e. do something like

```
long getWays(int n, vector<long> c) {
    long dp[n+1];
    memset(dp, 0ll, sizeof(dp));
    dp[0] = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(int ci=1; ci<=c.size(); ci++)
        {
            if(c[ci-1] > i) continue;
            dp[i] += dp[i-c[ci-1]];
        }
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

Why does the answer change?

Comment: `long dp[n+1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Valid C++ is `std::vector<long> dp(n+1,0);`, and then you don't need that `memset`.

Comment: *Why does the answer change ?* -- Use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: You are using `dp[i-c[ci-1]]` to calculate `dp[i]`. It only works if `dp[i-c[ci-1]]` is already calculated. Therefore the order is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code updates number of ways to compose values `dp[i]` with new coin.
After k-th round of outer loop we have `dp[]` array filled with combinations of k coins only, and the rest of coins is not used yet. If we make output of combinations themselves for **sorted** coin list, we will see **ordered** ones like `1  1  5` - 5 never will go before 1.

The second program at m-th round of outer loop fills m-th cell `dp[m]` using all possible coins. So we can get for `m=7` both `1  1  5` and `1  5  1` and `5 1 1` - all possible permutations. That's why result differs.