# Leetcode Target sum of dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm

Given *n* and *target*, find the number of combinations of number from [1,2,...,n] adding up to target. The number can be repeatedly picked (1 + 1 + 2 = 4), however the combinations cannot be duplicated ({1,1,2} and {1,2,1} are regard as one combination). e.g.

n = 2, target = 4: {1,1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,3}, {2,2}, so return 4

Since we only need to return the number of combinations, we use dynamic programming as following:

```
int sum(int n, int target) {
    vector<int> dp(target + 1);
    dp[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= target; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (i >= j) dp[i] += dp[i - j];
        }
    }
    return dp.back();
}
```

However this solution is for duplicated combinations:{1,1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,2,1}, {2,1,1}, {1,3}, {3,1} {2,2}, so return 7.

Do you know how to modify it to remove the duplications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple modification

```
  for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int i = j; i <= target; i++) {
            dp[i] += dp[i - j];
        }
    }
```

helps to avoid using small values after larger value, so code counts only sorted combinations

[Alike question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64871494/what-is-the-correct-order-to-traverse-the-states-in-the-popular-coin-change-dyna/64871959#64871959) with specific coin nominals instead of 1..n values